# Creating system image with precompilation for Scikit Learn in Julia

Tags: scikit-learn, julia, packagecompiler.jl

I used Package compiler package to build the system image for the ScikitLearn package. However, I am unable to add precompilation for the library in the system image.
My Code snippet to build the file is:

```
julia> using Package Compiler
julia> @time create_sysimage([:CSV, :ScikitLearn]; sysimage_path="sysimage-SkL-precompile.so", precompile_execution_file="code_SkL.jl")
```

The process without precompilation works fine but when the precompilation is added it throws an error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Symbol "ccall_PyImport_ImportModule_28677"not found
signal (22): SIGABRT
```

May I know the cause of this error and how to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ScikitLearn` is heavily relying on `PyCall`. Try including it in your sysimage.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I tried including `PyCall` but still, it throws the same error.